# Unexpected behavior of RDS snapshots in a replication array with an external master

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

RDS Snapshots don't seem to work as I would expect when set up with replication. I'd like to get some guidance on if I'm making incorrect assumptions, or just doing something wrong.

**Here's what happened:**

1. I set up an RDS instance as a slave to an external mysql instance (outside of AWS)
2. I let the instance catch up, replication was running successfully for a few days, taking nightly snapshots of the slave on RDS.
3. Some queries were run on the slave accidentally, causing errors for the replication, and causing the databases to get completely out of sync.
4. I restored the slave from a snapshot.

**What I expected:**

1. After the snapshot restored, replication on the new slave database would be able to catch back up to the position of the master.

**What actually happened:**

1. After the snapshot restored, data was restored, but replication settings were not.  `show slave status` returned null.

**TLDR**; The AWS documentation states that RDS snapshots back up the entire database instance, so I would expect all of its settings to be backed up as well, including settings for an external master, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  What are the limitations of RDS's snapshot capabilities, and how should replication with an external master be handled if the slave gets too far out of sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the replication errors that you mentioned in your question stopped replication for extended period, Amazon AWS RDS stops replication. This is done to prevent excessive storage requirements in the source side. When the RDS replica is restored using a snap shot, the new replica will never catch-up in that case because the binary logs are also deleted from the source in this case. This is mentioned in the AWS documentation but it also states that for this to happen the replication error should continue for a month.